# Intel 845GL and Ubuntu 14 32 bit

Tags: drivers, intel, inspiron

Dell Inspiron 1100 Laptop with Intel 845GL graphics. I have reset the ?UMA? from the 1M to the 8M as recommended (after installing Ubuntu 14). I used the terminal to edit grub and set the nomodeset, however instead of the window being in one corner with fuzzy lines, it is now in the center of the screen. This is ok, but the size of the window is still small. Does anyone know how to get the Intel 845GL to work with Ubuntu 14 32 bit?

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem with dell inspiron 1100 and how i have overcome the half screen problem caused by the 845gl.Boot up the old dell just after the boot screen appears press the power button to switch off then reboot the grub menu comes up click on lubuntu and i always get the full screen.